# How to set a fixed id for an Android resource

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a jar that at one point tries to access to access to the Android's resource with id 0x7f0b0064.

I need to add that jar to my project and make that id to resolve into a String resource of my choice.

How can I declare a string with a fixed id in compile time?

I tried to add:

In **public.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
      <public type="string" name="error_message" id="0x7f0b0064"/>
</resources>
```

In **string.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
      <string name="error_message">An error occurred</string>
</resources>
```

But it doesn't work. How can I do it?

Edit: The problem is that when call to a class in my jar. It attempts to create a Toast with a message, but the id of the string is not found in my resources:

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f0b0064
at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:312)
at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:286)
at com.customservices.CheckLocationService.a(Unknown Source)
at com.customservices.CheckLocationService.onStartCommand(Unknown Source)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3010)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1442) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Those ids are generated in compile time (in the R class), and afaik they can change each time, so don't rely on them. I'm curious about why would you need to do that.

Comment: I need it because the compiled jar attempts to retrieve a string from the resources with that id, I do not have the source code. And I get the exception: Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f0b0064

Comment: post the full stacktrace

Comment: You can decompile that jar and check the name of the id in the R.class file

Comment: @AshishRanjan stacktrace posted

Comment: is `com.customservices.CheckLocationService` your class or a library class?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the source of the jar and can you recompile it?

Reflection could help you get the correct id whatever it is.

Comment: You're pretty much out of luck. That jar is badly programmed. Check if it is pointing to some different .R file in another package. You might as well try to extract that .R with some decompiler, then attempt to edit it and put it back.

Comment: I tried but the decompiled code does not compile again since it uses bad syntax =(